# New "follow" feature?

Tags: support

So I opened a question link in the morning and noticed this new "follow" feature.

Can we know more details about this feature?

A screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Visit MSE [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/260388)

Comment: @Pandya Thanks you may want to close the question.